# Get height of dynamic child elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I want to dynamically set the heights of some elements using the heights of some other elements. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the references to the "source" objects and always run into an infinite loop. This is what I've tried so far. TimelineData is just a simple object with a few properties to populate the elements:

```js
const TimelineElement : React.FC<{data: TimelineData, ref : any}> = ({data, ref}) => {
  return <div className="timeline-element" ref={ref}>
    <div className="timeline-element-title">{data.title}</div>
    <div className="timeline-element-details">{data.details}</div>
  </div>;
}

export const Timeline : React.FC<{data: TimelineData[]}> = ({data}) => {
  const refs = data.map(() => createRef<HTMLElement>());
  const components = data.map(
    (r, i) => <TimelineElement ref={(el : any) => refs[i] = el} data={r}/>
  );
  const [heights, setHeights] = useState<any[]>([]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setHeights(refs.map(
      ref => ref.current?.tagName
    ));
  }, [components, refs]);
  return <div className="timeline">
    {components}
    {JSON.stringify(heights)}
  </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using `createRef` will create a new ref on each render, that will lead to execute `setHeights` which will cause re-rednering, and so on, there are few work arounds here, but I'd recommend using `useRef` hook instead, which will return the same ref

## **UPDATE:**

in addition to the above answer, to handle your case, you can store multiple elements in one created ref instead of creating array of refs in a loop:

```
const refs = useRef([]);
...
...
<TimelineElement ref={(el: any) => (refs.current[i] = el)} data={r} />
...
...
setHeights(refs.current?.map((element) => element.tagName));
```

Here, you got the issue of refs solved, but you'll have the same infinity loop because of another part, your `useLayoutEffect` depends on `components` which will get a new value on each render, here we can use `useMemo` to solve that:

```
const components = useMemo(() => data.map(
    (r, i) => <TimelineElement ref={(el : any) => refs[i] = el} data={r}/>
  ), [refs]);
```

one more thing that needs to be fixed, don't give `ref` to a functional component, you can rename it to a different name:

```
<TimelineElement elementRef={(el: any) => (refs.current[i] = el)} data={r} />
```

so after these points, here is the full code:

```
const TimelineElement: React.FC<{ data: TimelineData; elementRef: any }> = ({
  data,
  elementRef
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="timeline-element" ref={elementRef}>
      <div className="timeline-element-title">{data.title}</div>
      <div className="timeline-element-details">{data.details}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Timeline: React.FC<{ data: TimelineData[] }> = ({ data }) => {
  const refs = useRef([]);
  const [heights, setHeights] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const components = useMemo(
    () =>
      data.map((r, i) => (
        <TimelineElement elementRef={(el: any) => (refs.current[i] = el)} data={r} />
      )),
    [refs]
  );

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setHeights(refs.current?.map((element) => element.tagName));
  }, [components]);

  return (
    <div className="timeline">
      {components}
      {JSON.stringify(heights)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

One last note: don't forget to add a unique `key` to elements in `map()` ;)

Comment: I cannot use `useRef` inside a dynamic loop though

Comment: @Chrisstar, sorry for not posting a complete answer from the first time, please check the updated answer :)

Comment: Hello @Zac I really appreciate your answer, at least the infinite recursion is gone (I suspect useMemo has done the trick, which in itself is problematic because that's not how it's supposed to be used according to react documentation). The problem now is thar when useLayoutEffect is called refs.current still is an empty array, which doesn't help me solving my original problem